# Show the improper integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x^3-ax)}{x}dx$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

This is an exercise for the Dirichlet test for the convergence of improper integrals. This exercise is from the book called “A Course of Modern Analysis”. It does not specify what $a$, but I am thinking $a$ is a nonnegative number. I am not sure if this assumption is legit. Clearly, $\frac{1}{x}$ converges to 0 as $x \to \infty$. I am struggle to show $|\int_0^L \sin(x^3-ax)dx|$ for all $L$ is bounded. I tried to use u-sub but it does not make the problem easier. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x>\sqrt{\frac{a}{3}}$ we have that $g(x)=x^3-ax$ is an increasing function whose inverse function $h(x)$ behaves like $\sqrt[3]{x}$ for large values of $x$. $g(h(x))=x$ leads to $h'(x)=\frac{1}{g'(h(x))}=\frac{1}{3h(x)^2-a}$ and this gives

$$ \int_{\sqrt{a/3}}^{L}\sin(x^3-ax)\,dx = \int_{g(\sqrt{a/3})}^{g(L)}\frac{\sin(t)}{3h(t)^2-a}\,dt. $$
The last integral is convergent by Dirichlet's test/integration by parts since $\sin t$ has a bounded primitive and $\frac{1}{3h(t)^2-a}$ decreases to zero. As a consequence, $\int_{0}^{L}\sin(x^3-ax)\,dx$ is bounded.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

$$\sin(x^3-ax)=\sin(x^3)\cos(ax)-\cos(x^3)\sin(ax)$$

Answer (score 2):

As $u \to 0$, $\sin(u)/u \to 1$, so in particular $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^3 - ax)}{x} = \left( \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x^3 - ax)}{x^3 - ax} \right) \left( \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^3 - ax}{x} \right) = 1 \times -a = -a,$$

since $x^3 - ax \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. So the integrand is bounded in a neighborhood of $x = 0$ and, in fact, has a removable discontinuity at the endpoint $x = 0$.

As for convergence on the infinite end, looking at a graph, it's instantly clear that the integral is equal to an alternating series, with the positive terms being the areas above the curve, and the negative terms being the areas below the curve:
[image]

The mildly tedious part is verifying that the $n$th term of this series (the area between consecutive x-intercepts) is approaching $0$ as $x \to \infty$, but once you have that, you can just say that the improper integral converges by Alternating Series Test. This is a common way to handle improper integrals of functions that oscillate forever. The integrand doesn't have to approach $0$, it just has to be bounded: the same strategy can verify that, for instance, $$\int_0^\infty \cos(x^p) dx \text{ converges for any } p > 1.$$

Answer (score -1):

*Hint.* Note that $$\left|\frac{\sin (x^3-ax)}{x}\right|\le \frac1x$$ for all $x>0.$ And it doesn't matter what $a$ is.

Comment: You have already given the answer.

Answer (score -2):

*Hint.* Note that $$\left|\frac{\sin (x^3-ax)}{x}\right|\le \frac1x$$ for all $x>0.$

Comment: This is not enough to conclude anything.